# What happens exactly in the electron transport chain when there's no oxygen

Tags: molecular-biology, bioenergetics

what is the mechanism of hypoxia in the electron transport chain? It stops because there's no terminal electron acceptor so the IV complex become "stuck" with an electron? There's no other molecule that can accept electrons just like the oxygen?

Comment: [This article](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abi7495) suggests fumarate is an alternative terminal acceptor under low-oxygen conditions

Comment: @Aditya thank you.